# Combine two field table into one column list

Tags: mysql

```
select Client.FirstName + ' ' + Client.LastName 'Client Name',Staff.FirstName + ' ' + Staff.LastName 'Staff Name' from Client
inner join Job on Job.ClientID = Client.ClientID
inner join Staff on Staff.StaffID = Job.StaffID
Order by Client.FirstName,Client.LastName,Staff.FirstName,Staff.Lastname desc
```

I have to combine the Client and Staff FirstName/LastName into one single list using SQL. They're in different tables and I'm not really sure how it can be done.

Comment: `Concat(Client.FirstName, ' ', Client.LastName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL `+` is for addition. Use the CONCAT function instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Client.FirstName, ' ', Client.LastName) AS `Client Name`
     , CONCAT(Staff.FirstName, ' ', Staff.LastName) AS `Staff Name`
```

Or use the NULL-skipping CONCAT_WS function:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', Client.FirstName, Client.LastName) AS `Client Name`
     , CONCAT_WS(' ', Staff.FirstName, Staff.LastName) AS `Staff Name`
```